# Triple Monitor on AMD Card with 3 HDMI Screens

Tags: graphics-card, multiple-monitors, hdmi, dvi, eyefinity

I have 2 AMD 280x cards.

Card A has

1. Mini DP x2
2. HDMI
3. DVI

Card B has

1. DP
2. HDMI
3. DVI x2

When I got my DVI to HDMI converter to connect with 2 HDMI to DVI and one HDMI to HDMI, I thought I'd finally solved the three screen issue.
To my despair, it turns out I had not.

How should I go about 3 screens with crossfire?
I have the crossfire cable, sufficient power, and sufficient motherboard, but I'm thoroughly stymied on this connector business.  Whenever I try to read up on the internet about it, there seems to be a lot of disagreement.

Am I having a connector issue?
Does this have to do with active converters for display port connectors?
What works and why?

Comment: "To my despair, it turns out I had not." What happened? Did one of the monitors not work? Did the computer explode into a million pieces? Did you create a inter-dimensional wormhole to the demon dimension where Cthulhu crawled through the monitor and set upon your mortal flesh?

Comment: PS Try disabling Cross fire.

Comment: Only 2 of the 3 screens may be enabled. Cthulu stays in the corner and laughs at my frustration, not too much of a bother there.

Comment: I was able to make all three screens work again once I moved one of the screens onto the second GPU, but then crossfire with eyefinity is no longer possible. I would shrug this off as an annoyance but I would like to make sure my game works with crossfire.

Comment: Your GPU only has hardware to drive two monitors each. This is very common. Each connector is routed to the drivers as displays are connected. You need to disable cross fire two use both GPUs. One work around would be to drive the 3rd display on the IGP and use the first and second on the crossfire.

Comment: how then does one set up 3 screen eyefinity?

Comment: You need to network the monitors http://support.amd.com/en-us/search/faq/154

Comment: I will attempt the setup using the Plugable® Active DisplayPort to HDMI Adapter, which will arrive on Friday.  I'll report on whether that solves the issue after my head stops reeling from HDMI being called legacy so quickly, though I suppose it has been 10 years.  Thank you for your assistance, @Aron.

Comment: I think you want this as well http://www.evga.com/Products/Product.aspx?pn=200-DP-1301-L1

Comment: using an HDMI <-> HDMI, Active Displayport to HDMI Adapter, DVI <-> HDMI has all three screens working!  a displayport hub would probably be nicer...